# How can I restore /etc/apt/keyrings directory?

Tags: apt, gnupg, restore, keyrings

I am new to Linux, and when I was trying to install ***postgresql*** on my **ubuntu 22.04**, in one of the steps while adding the necessary gpg key, being not accurate it seems I deleted all the ***gpg*** files from `/etc/apt/keyrings` directory, because `ls` command shows it's being empty now. But I remember there were a lot of them containing *"ubuntu"* in their name. Well, and I don't know how to backup the necessary files. I guess there might be some options to return all the standard ubuntu gpg keys, but I couldn't find the necessary information myself. Could you please help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: `dpkg -S /etc/apt/keyrings` and reinstall these packages

Comment: Welcome Helionthebus. Are you sure about that path? I expected right one for apt is: `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` or `/usr/share/keyrings/` same as in [`ubuntu-keyring` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/ubuntu-keyring/filelist)

Comment: @DanielT that command returns `apt: /etc/apt/keyrings`. What exactly shall I reinstall?

Comment: Oh, thank you, @user.dz. I checked `/usr/share/keyrings/`directory and yes! the files are there! So, the directory `/etc/apt/keyrings/` is ok to be empty or anyway I deleted files from there? It seems I might be worrying about nothing, I'm sorry ...

Comment: @Helionthebus, good, also `/usr/share/keyrings/` is for external repositories. Ok to delete any keys that are no longer in use in source.list files.

Comment: @user.dz, thank you! Now I understand what are these directories for and what should be stored there!

Comment: I also want to leave [here a link with explanation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437207/what-is-the-right-place-to-put-keyrings-for-repositories), maybe it will help someone like me for better understanding!

Comment: It is better if you write an answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write the answer to my question. Actually what happened was that I mixed two directories: `/etc/apt/keyrings` and `/usr/share/keyrings`. So, in my case, I didn't actually delete anything. When system told me to put gpg key to `/etc/apt/keyrings` directory, I did and checked what else was there and got confused, as I knew there ought to be more keys. But, in the end, now I understand that though these directories are for gpg keys and look similar, but they are different. So, while installing some soft and adding it's repo, you get gpg key and you need to store it to `/usr/share/keyrings` directory. But in some certain cases when the key is for internal usage just inside your computer (as I understood), the key is stored in `/etc/apt/keyrings`.
Thanks to @uzer.dz and to this [question/answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437207/what-is-the-right-place-to-put-keyrings-for-repositories) I understood how it works. Maybe this will help someone else like me.